# Session get HTTP_HOST (and don't throw error in testing mode)

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-4, environment-variables

I would like to use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` in my code, without the code breaking when I use PHPUnit. I'm using Laravel, but not sure If the solution is to:

1. create my own getHttpHost Method that returns `""` if the `$_SERVER` Array doesn't have a key called `HTTP_HOST`
2. use another existing php function that doesn't throw an error when trying to get the `HTTP_HOST`
3. use a Laravel specific function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the server variable in the PHPUnit configuration:
http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

it ought to be something like:

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <server name='HTTP_HOST' value='http://yoursite.com' />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define this var via phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <server name='HTTP_HOST' value='http://host.dev'/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Read [documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables) for more information.